# How to find frequency of elements in 2xn dimensional array in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have an 2xn (2-columns and n-rows) dimensional array, where the values will be in the range of 1 to 60 (only integers). I need to find frequency of rows as mentioned below for clarity.

## Input Array

0-> 9,11
1-> 9,10
2-> 2,10
3-> 9,11
4-> 9,11

## Output

(9,11) -> 3 times
(9,10) -> 1 time
(2,10) -> 1 time

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Write a routine to determine if the tuples are identical.

Comment: Like [this](http://ideone.com/RD9WcJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two values on each row into a single identifier, and just count the occurrences of each identifier (i.e., a histogram). For example, if `c1` and `c2` are the values in the two columns, and `1 <= c1`, `c1 <= 60`, `1 <= c2`, `c2 <= 60`, then you could use

```
k = (c1 - 1) * 60 + (c2 - 1)
```

to get `0 <= k`, `k < 3600`. This means there are only 3600 different unique combinations values on each row. So, create an array of that size, and increment the `k`th entry for each row.

To output the counts, just loop over all possible `k`, noting that

```
c1 = (k / 60) + 1
c2 = (k % 60) + 1
```

---

In general, if you have integers from `imin`  to `imax`, inclusive, you can pack them into a larger integer using

```
base = imax - imin + 1
packed = (i1 - imin) + base * ((i2 - imin) + base * ((i3 - imin) + ... ))
```

and unpack using

```
i1 = imin + (packed % base)
i2 = imin + ((packed / base) % base)
i3 = imin + ((packed / (base * base)) % base)
```

and so on. `0 <= packed`, so you can use an unsigned integer type for `packed`.

The type has to be large enough to hold the packed value, of course. If there are three values, then `packed < base * base * base`.